# Hoisting variables and functions parameters?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Consider the following examples:

```
function a(a){
    console.log(a);
    function a(){}
    var a=7;
    console.log(a);
}
a(10)
```

So why is the first printing is a function rather than 10;

Comment: Precisely because of *hoisting*. You're using that word, yet you seem to not have investigated what it means...?!

Comment: I know hoisting, but when there is a function parameter I will confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function declarations are parsed at compile time itself, and the declarations are moved to the top of the function, like this

```
function a(a) {
    var a = function a() {};
    console.log(a);
    a = 7;
    console.log(a);
}
a(10)
```

That is why you are getting `[Function: a]` or something similar in the first `console.log`. When the line `a = 7;` is executed, `a` is assigned the value `7`. That is why the second `console.log` prints `7`.

Comment: When the function is executed, function parameters is how to parsed?

Comment: @SIMDD They are similar to a variable declared within the function.

Comment: But in this example, after hoisting, didn't see function parameters assigned?

Comment: Which function you are talking about? Also what parameters?

Comment: the arguments **10**  ?

Comment: When the function is invoked, `a` will be 10 only. But the first line of the function is assigning the function object to the variable `a`. So the value 10 will be replaced with the function object.